# Problems with Atom, Linter, linter-flake8 and bash

Tags: linux, bash, python, fedora, atom-editor

I just installed Atom editor and some packages, like linter and linter-flake8.

When I try to edit python code, I receive the following error:

```
[Linter] Error running Flake8 Error: /bin/sh: module: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
/bin/sh: error importing function definition for `module'
/bin/sh: ml: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
/bin/sh: error importing function definition for `ml'
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/lipton/.atom/pac…xec/lib/index.js:56)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962)
    at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:381)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:182)
    at Pipe._handle.close (net.js:606)
```

After doing some research it seems there are two enviroment vars with malformed  functions:

```
BASH_FUNC_ml%%=() {  eval $($LMOD_DIR/ml_cmd "$@")
BASH_FUNC_module%%=() {  eval $($LMOD_CMD bash "$@") && eval $(${LMOD_SETTARG_CMD:-:} -s sh)
```

Some people have had similar problems and solved it putting `unset` in `.bashrc` like:

```
unset BASH_FUNC_module
unset BASH_FUNC_ml
```

But it does not unset these vars.

I'm using Fedora 31 and found other possible solutions, but none apply to my case.

In this [case](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1146958) have a similar problem, but I don't have the `enviroment-module` package:

[Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/365799/bin-sh-error-importing-function-definition-for-module) is another similar problem, but I don't have the error outside Atom:

[Here](https://github.com/AtomLinter/linter-puppet-lint/issues/68), another similar problem, but I don't have `scl-utils` nor `enviroment-modules`.

Could somebody give me a hint on this.

Thanks

Comment: I found out that if I start Atom from the command line does not have the problem reported, it only happens if I start from the menu of Cinnamon Desktop Environment.